# Hadoop crashed while running terasort?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am working with Hadoop single node, later may move on to multinode. Right now the same node is master as well as slave, hence `namenode`, `datanode` `resource manager` and `node manager` are running on the same PC.

Whenever I trigger `terasort` on seperate testing disk mounted on `/home/hadoop/hdfs` (here `hadoop` is user name), it fails with following errors:

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1429766544852_0001_m_001255_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for attempt_1429766544852_0001_m_001255_0_spill_1.out
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:398)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnOutputFiles.getSpillFileForWrite(YarnOutputFiles.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1467)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:699)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:769)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)

15/04/23 11:36:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1429766544852_0001_m_001258_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:236)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.close(IFile.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1633)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$900(MapTask.java:852)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$SpillThread.run(MapTask.java:1510)

Error: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:236)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IFile$Writer.close(IFile.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1633)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$900(MapTask.java:852)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$SpillThread.run(MapTask.java:1510)

Error: java.io.IOException: Spill failed
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.checkSpillException(MapTask.java:1540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$300(MapTask.java:852)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(MapTask.java:1352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(MapTask.java:1329)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeByte(DataOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.writeVLong(WritableUtils.java:273)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.writeVInt(WritableUtils.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.write(Text.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
```

Basically, `spill failed`, `Disk checker`, `no space left` etc.

When I looked into the issue, keep running `df -h` in separate terminal gave the clue that it is using `/` directory for some internal operations as the job was in progress. When no space left on `/` the job failed.

I tried changing `hadoop.tmp.dir` to some other mounted disk. It worked fine but again failed as that disk was also not having enough space.

**My question is why is it happening, can we avoid this issue at all? Or, what exact parameters be configured in `.xml` config files so that to restrict it to within `RAM` or use disk space but make sure not to fail the job and use whatever space it has but dont crash due to any error which I have mentioned?**

Thanks in advance.

PS: I have studied about alomst all config parameters and gone thourgh roughly all kinds of hit & trial but still it failed. Hence, I thought of asking here, hope you may help.

Comment: Could you post your configuration files here ?

Comment: There are lot of changes I have to in config files. I will try to run with minimal changes which is required and put the same here. But the thing is if you know any parameter which can be set to avoid spill then please do post here.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using Hadoop 2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why is it happening

So to give you a better understanding, Mapper's as soon as their task is complete the intermediate output is spilled to disk (specified by `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` whose default value is `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nm-local-dir`), of course if the data does not fit in memory of the Mapper then also a spill is made and is merged at the end of the task and written back eventually to disk.

Similarly the reducer has to copy the intermediate data from Mapper's local filesystem to it's own local filesystem to process the data.

So, for example if you are running terasort on 100G of data with 4 mapper's & one reducer then assuming your mapper's have generated 25G of intermediate data, then the reducer has to have 100G free space on its local filesystem to processing it.

> can we avoid this issue at all?

In your case increasing task's wouldn't help as it's a single machine.

Only way to avoid the problem is to add more NodeManager's so that you could get more disk space from that node's to process the job.

> what exact parameters be configured in .xml config files so that to restrict it to within RAM

You cannot restrict the MapReduce job to just use RAM as for the shuffle process to happen data has to be written to disk.

> or use disk space but make sure not to fail the job and use whatever space it has but don't crash due to any error which I have mentioned?

You have to have enough disk space for intermediate task's output on your cluster for the job to get processed.